# Jquery .next() is not working when I'm trying to hide the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a div if certain value are selected in a drop down. I'm using 
`$(this).next('.selectNos').hide();` but it won't do the job for some reason. Please can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addCondition').on('change','.conOperatorC', function(e){       
    if ($('option:selected',this).text() == "In" || $('option:selected',this).text() == " Not In")  {
    alert($('option:selected',this).text());
    $(this).next('.selectNos').hide();
    }
    else {
    $(this).next(':select').hide(); 
    }
});
$('.conOperatorC').trigger('change');
});

<div id="addCondition">
<select id="conOperator0" name="conOperator0" class="standard_select conOperatorC" style="width:147px;">
      <option>blah</option><option>
      <option>Contains</option>
      <option>In</option>
      <option>Not In</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="conValue0" name="conValue0" class="short_input" value="" style="width:147px;">

<div class="selectNos">
    <select id="conValuedd0" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="display: none; ">
       <option value="option1">blah</option>
       <option value="option2">blah</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" style="width: 225px; "><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>Please Select</span></button>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `next` selects exactly the **next** element. You'd better use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).siblings('.selectNos').hide();
```

BTW, in order to get the selected value in your case you can use `this.value` instead of `$('option:selected', this).text()`.

Comment: He have to add `value` attribute to his options first.

Comment: @JBRTRND No need. You can try.

Comment: If a value attribute is not provided, the default value is set to the text within the option.